# Django form with label directly in the Field, but disappear on typing

Tags: django, forms

I would like to achieve the same effect as google login page that the Label of the text field is shown in the field itself. When any characters is typed in the filed, the label automatically disappeared.

I know how to achieve similar effect with html + java script, like:

```
<input type="text" name="" id="" value="Email" class="gray"  onclick="if(this.value=='Email')
{this.value='';this.className='black'}" onblur="if(this.value=='')    
{this.value='Email';this.className='gray'}" />
```

But could django form does the same effect? I know I can specify `initial` in the CharField, but it won't disappear on typing.

```
forms.CharField(max_length=100, label=_("Email"), initial='xxx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a html5 prop called placeholdertext. Here is a Blogpost about how to use it with django forms. [Django HTML5 input placeholders](http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2010/09/03/django-html5-input-placeholders.html)
Excerpt:

`class MyForm(Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput({ "placeholder": "Joe Recruiter" }))`